# Pure-ftpd-mysql permissions

Tags: linux, debian, pureftpd

Hello all!

I install pure-ftpd-mysql Debian 8 Linux
64bit

How to change permissions?

uid: 2001
gid: 2001

files in /www/www/directory/directory
how to allow change files? folder permission 755 and needed 777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Using -R for Recurse (man chown, man chmod)
~$ sudo chown -R user:group /www/www/directory/directory
~$ sudo chown user:group /www/www/directory/directory/afile
~$ sudo chmod -R 755 /www/www/directory/directory
~$ sudo chmod 777 /www/www/directory/directory/directory/afile
```

User and group can be found with

```
~$ id
```

But in your case maybe:

```
~$ cat /etc/passwd|grep '2001'

~$ cat /etc/group|grep '2001'
or
~$ cat /etc/group|grep 'user name VALUE FOUND BY cat /etc/passwd'
```

The user and group should be the same as those running pure-ftpd.